# Where in Dubai can I see supercars?

Tags: sightseeing, dubai, souvenirs

I really enjoy sports cars and Dubai seems to be the best place to find them. I have already seen some Mustangs and Camaros, but I was wondering if there is a specific place that has a lot of supercars like Lamborghinis or Ferraris that I can visit.

Bonus points if you know of a place where I can get a souvenir like a Lamborghini shaped keychain or magnet.

Comment: You can probably start with the relevant dealerships...

Comment: @jcaron If possible, I'd like to see them out in the open. Besides, I have no means of buying one, so going to a dealership would likely be too much ^^'

Comment: One way might be to look for prominent motorsport events being hosted in Dubai. They may have an exhibition venue where such cars may be parked for public viewing. Few years ago I was in Lugano on the weekend of an [XCat powerboat race](https://x-cat.racing/) and they had an exhibition of collection of luxury boats, cars and bikes in the main town square.